# how to execute somecode after resolve or reject are executed in Promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I have promise which may resolve or reject after api call, I want to execute some code either in resolve or reject callbacks, I want to execute some other code after either of these callback is done. How to achieve it.

```
ApiHelper.myPromise.call(this, 'Event').then(function(response) {
            ToolsHelper.DynamicAttributes.setDAMetaDataCache.call($this, 'Event', response, '#addEventDynamicAttribute');
            ApiHelper.ApiResponseHandler.hideSpinner();

            var eventEditFormView = new EventEditFormView({'parentObj': $this.parentObj, 'method': 'add'});
            eventEditFormView.context['dynamicAttributeMetaData'] = $this.context['dynamicAttributeMetaData'];
            eventEditFormView.context['newAccordions'] = $this.context['newAccordions'];
            $this.$('#event-edit').append(eventEditFormView.$el);
            eventEditFormView.render();
            eventEditFormView.delegateEvents();
        }).catch(function(response) {console.log('err', response);
            ApiHelper.ApiResponseHandler.logError(response, 'event_base_view', ' setDynamicAttributes', 'catalog/metadata/v3/dynamicattributes', 'v3');
            ApiHelper.ApiResponseHandler.hideSpinner();
        });
```

Comment: Put the code in a function and call that function in both callbacks. Or add another `.then(...)` call.

Comment: I don't want to call another function in both callbacks. Can I add then after catch again? Will it be called after first then or catch?

Comment: Yes it will, see example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chain thens together. If any of the thens throw an error it will go to the catch.

```
     ApiHelper.myPromise.call(this, 'Event')
     .then(function(response){
         ApiHelper.ApiResponseHandler.hideSpinner();
         return response;
     }
     .then(function(response) {
     ToolsHelper.DynamicAttributes.setDAMetaDataCache.call($this, 'Event', response, '#addEventDynamicAttribute');
        //ApiHelper.ApiResponseHandler.hideSpinner();

        var eventEditFormView = new EventEditFormView({'parentObj': $this.parentObj, 'method': 'add'});
        eventEditFormView.context['dynamicAttributeMetaData'] = $this.context['dynamicAttributeMetaData'];
        eventEditFormView.context['newAccordions'] = $this.context['newAccordions'];
        $this.$('#event-edit').append(eventEditFormView.$el);
        eventEditFormView.render();
        eventEditFormView.delegateEvents();
    }).catch(function(response) {console.log('err', response);
        ApiHelper.ApiResponseHandler.logError(response, 'event_base_view', ' setDynamicAttributes', 'catalog/metadata/v3/dynamicattributes', 'v3');
        //ApiHelper.ApiResponseHandler.hideSpinner();
    });
```